# Selenium XPATH I am trying to find the checkbox from a table where name is in col 2 and col 3

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a html table with lots of rows and 3 columns. col1 has a checkbox, col2 has a string text and col 3 has a string text. Using XPath I am trying to locate the checkbox where col 3 has the text "Address" and col 2 has the text "CLEAN_AUDIT"

There is also a row in the table which has "CLEAN_AUDIT" in col2 and col3 has the text "Name"

If i use the following XPATH it will locate all the checkboxes which has "CLEAN_AUDIT" in col2 This is no good for me because I just need to locate "CLEAN_AUDIT" which has "Address"

```
//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail"]//div[(text()="CLEAN_AUDIT")]/preceding::td[1]//input
```

I don't want to use td[1] because the table can change, the data can move to a different place. Also i would like to use text in the xpath somehow because if i wanted to find the checkbox where "CLEAN_AUDIT" is in col2 and "Name" is in col3

The HTML snippet is (Apologies it is a bit long):

```
<table id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail" class="GJPPK2LBJE" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
<thead aria-hidden="false">
    <colgroup>
        <tbody style="">
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="10">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">LAST_DATA_CHANGED</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="11">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">FORENAME_UNN</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="12">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SURNAME_UNN</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="13">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">TITLE</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="14">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">FORENAME</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="15">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SURNAME</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="16">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SUFFIX</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="17">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">GENDER</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="18">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SOURCE_FIELDS</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="19">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">CLEAN_AUDIT</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="20">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">EXPANDED_CLEAN_AUDIT</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="21">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">CATEGORY</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="22">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SOURCEMAP_ID</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="23">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">TIME_STAMP</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="24">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">LAST_SEEN</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="25">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">STANDARDISED_DATA</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="26">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">ISRN</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="27">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">BISRN</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="28">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">USRN</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="29">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">ULN</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="30">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">POBOX</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="31">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">DEPT</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="32">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">ORGNAME</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="33">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SUBBNAME</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="34">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">FLOOR</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="35">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">BLOCK</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="36">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">BUILDING</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="37">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">COMPLEX</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="38">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">BNUM</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="39">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SUBSTREET</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="40">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">STREET</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="41">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">LOCALITY1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="42">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">LOCALITY2</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="43">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">LOCALITY3</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="44">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">LOCALITY4</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="45">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">POSTCODE</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="46">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">COUNTRY</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="47">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">X</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="48">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">Y</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="49">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">ADDRCL_AUDIT</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="50">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">XREF</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="51">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">SOURCE_FIELDS</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD GJPPK2LBJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="52">
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED GJPPK2LBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-555" style="outline-style:none;">CLEAN_AUDIT</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD GJPPK2LBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-556" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="53">
                </tbody>
                <tbody style="display: none;">
                    <tfoot style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"/>
                </table>
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: If you scroll down the html snippet Clean_Audit is at the bottom.  I pasted the html into notepad++, Set language to XML -> Plugins -> XML tools -> Pretty print

Comment: I will try pasting again a better format html,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your page source, I tried this and found it working:

```
//td/div[text()='CLEAN_AUDIT']/../following-sibling::td/div[text()='Address']/../../td//input
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath will select the checkbox of the row that contains "CLEAN_AUDIT" and "Name":

```
//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail"]//tr[.//div[text()="CLEAN_AUDIT"] and .//div[text()="Name"]]//input[@type="checkbox"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for it being a little long

```
//table[@id='reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail']/descendant::tr[contains(.,'CLEAN_AUDIT') and contains(., 'Address')]/descendant::input[@type='checkbox']
```